# How to not limit mongo query in python by pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to use find method to query all records, but after a while, find method is finished.

code like this:

```
print doc.find().count()
idx = 0
for record in doc.find():
    idx = idx+1
    print('%d, [%s]\n') % (idx, record['desc'])
```

print this:

```
4137381
...
25344, [1831****683|00|20160122040901|02|699056|1530831000|0|20160122040901] 
25345, [1598****686|00|20160111162049|02|699056|1530831000|0|20160111162049]
```

Comment: Could you be more detailed, since normally it would find everything for you. Could you show the results too.

Comment: @Phong Phung it's ok, can u help me?

Comment: On my db it always return all. So you mean it stops somewhere in middle, not going through all records of your table. I think you need to contact the IT admin who is maintaining you database to see the log fo the server if it reports any error. but first you could try `df = pd.DataFrame(list(conn.find()))` with pd from pandas `import pandas as pd` to see the len of dataframe.

Comment: @Phong Phung I see. Thank u very much.